# Let $A$ be a normal matrix. Prove $\left \| (A+I)v \right \| = \left \| (A^{*}+I)v \right \|$

Tags: linear-algebra

Need some help with the following:

Let $A$ be a **normal** $N \times N$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$. Prove 
$\left \| (A+I)v \right \| = \left \| (A^{*}+I)v \right \|$ for any $v\in  \mathbb{C}^{n}$.

Is it some how related to A eigenvalues?

Comment: Are you considering this in an inner product space? If yes, then you can use the definition of norm and rhe fact that $A $ commutes with its adjoint.

Comment: Hint: If $A$ is normal, then so is $B = A+I$. Now write $$\|Bv\|^2=\langle Bv,Bv\rangle=\langle v, B^*Bv\rangle $$ Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any normal matrix $N$ we have

$$\|Nx\|^2 = \langle Nx, Nx\rangle = \langle N^*Nx, x\rangle = \langle NN^*x,x\rangle = \langle N^*x,N^*x\rangle = \|N^*x\|^2, \forall x\in\mathbb{C}^n$$

Now, if $A$ is normal then $A + I$ is also normal:

\begin{align}
(A + I)(A+I)^* &= (A+I)(A^*+I) \\
&= AA^* + A + A^* + I \\
&= A^*A + A + A^* + I \\
&= (A^*+I)(A+I)\\
&= (A+I)^*(A+I)
\end{align}

So we conclude $$\|(A+I)v\| = \|(A+I)^*v\| = \|(A^*+I)v\|$$

for all $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Prove it if $A$ is diagonal, and then diagonalize.